# iTerm2: All windows moved back to first Desktop after sleep

Tags: macos-catalina, iterm2

On MacOS Catalina macbook pro I have multiple iTerm2 windows spread over multiple desktops (on a dual monitor setup). Whenever I wake up my macbook from sleep all iTerm2 windows from all desktops have moved to Desktop 1 (the Desktop on my macbook itself). Requiring me to move all iTerm2 windows back to their respective Desktops by hand. An annoying thing to do everytime my macbooks goes to sleep (which is rather often). Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?